# Solving ODE in Mathematica

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematica

I want to solve an ODE in the form $\{y'[t] == f[y[t]], y[2] == \{1, 2, 3\}\}$ using NDSolve in Mathematica, where $f: R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ is defined as follows,

```
f[y_] := {2 y[[1]] + 1, 3 y[[2]] + y[[3]], 2 y[[3]] + y[[1]]}
s = NDSolve[{y'[t] == f[y[t]], y[2] == {1, 2, 3}}, y, {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[First[y /. s][t], {t, 0, 10}]
```

However, when I run the code it says "Part::partw: "Part 2 of y(t) does not exist."". How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Did you forget double brackets in your expression?

Comment: Hm, I do not know if Mathematica supports functions taking more than 1 arguments in NDSolve. Try to formulate question in terms of yx, yy and yz, instead, each taking t as argument, and they represent x, y resp. z.

Comment: If I remove $f$, e.g. {y'[t] == 2 y[t], y[2] == {1, 2, 3}}, it can be easily solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing definition of $y$ and making as many equations as there are functions in $y$ could help here. This one works:

```
f[y_] := {2 y[[1]] + 1, 3 y[[2]] + y[[3]], 2 y[[3]] + y[[1]]}
y[t_] = {y1[t], y2[t], y3[t]};
s = NDSolve[{#[[1]] == #[[2]]&/@Transpose[{y'[t], f[y[t]]}], 
             #[[1]] == #[[2]]&/@Transpose[{y[2], {1, 2, 3}}]}, 
             y[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[First[y[t] /. s], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Well, it really works but what's the difference between #[[1]] == #[[2]]&/@Transpose[{y'[t], f[y[t]]}] and y'[t] == f[y[t]]?

Comment: The first one gives list of three equalities and the second only one equality (of lists) which seems not to work.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, your solution is perfect for the above problem. But actually, the function $f$ must be more complicated than the above one. It has some local variables and ifs. When I use something like this f[y_] := Module[{test}, If[y[[1]] > 2, test = 1, test = 2]; 
   Return[{test y[[2]], y[[2]] + y[[3]], y[[3]] + y[[1]]}]]; I get an error NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative t==2. Any idea?

Comment: @Mohsen: I'd try to use `Piecewise[]` instead of `If[]`. Something like `f[y_List] := {Piecewise[{{1, y[[1]] > 2}, {2, True}}]*y[[2]], y[[2]] + y[[3]], y[[3]] + y[[1]]}`

Answer (score 2):

[`Thread[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) is your friend:

```
f[y_] := {2 y[[1]] + 1, 3 y[[2]] + y[[3]], 2 y[[3]] + y[[1]]};
y[t_] = {y1[t], y2[t], y3[t]};
s = NDSolve[Join[Thread[y'[t] == f[y[t]]], Thread[y[2] == {1, 2, 3}]], 
   y[t], {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[First[y[t] /. s], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks J.M., good point. Do you have any idea about my comment under Andrew's answer?